# Given $f,g$ analytic and an equality show $0$ is not in a closed line segment

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D= \{ z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and $T= \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$. Let $\Omega$ be an open set $\Omega \supset D \cup T$

Let $f,g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and satisfy that $|f(z)+g(z)| < |f(z)|+|g(z)|$ for all $z\in T$.

Fix $z_0\in T$, and let $S$ denote the closed line segment in $\mathbb{C}$ which has endpoints at $f(z_0)$ and at $-g(z_0)$. Prove that $0\notin S$.

We have $|z_0|=1$

By the inequality, we have $|f(z_0)+g(z_0)| < |f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|$.

I don't see how this goes. If we go by contradiction and assume $0\in S$. I'm not sure what can go wrong here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hint: $S=\{tf(z_0)-(1-t)g(z_0) : 0\le t\le 1\}$. So you assume $tf(z_0)-(1-t)g(z_0)=0$ and show this implies $|f(z_0)+g(z_0)|=|f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|$.

Comment: More generally for two elements $u,v$ in a  normed space, if $\|u+v\|<\|u\|+\|v\| $ then $u$ cannot be equal $rv$ for a positive constant $r.$